# Converting spherical electric potential to cartesian coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, change-of-variable

How can I convert this spherical scalar function...

$$\Phi(r,\phi,\theta)=kq\left[\frac{1}{r-d\cos(\theta)} - \frac{1}{r+d\cos(\theta)}\right]$$

to, what should be, its rectangular equivalent...

$$\Phi(x,y,z)=kq\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-d)^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z+d)^2}}\right]$$

I tried making the substitutions, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \right)$, but to no avail. Any guidance would be appreciated.

FYI: This problem comes from Griffiths' Electrodynamics example 3.2. He finds the electric potential surrounding a point charge at offset $d$. I am trying to do the same but I started out in spherical coordinates. I would like to verify against his solution in rectangular coordinates.

Comment: Are you sure about your spherical expression? That doesn't look right if this is an image charge

Comment: @NinadMunshi I would trust Griffith's more. Here is my reference for the spherical solution: ([question 1a](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ece303/Homeworks/homework2sol.pdf))

Comment: I don't see anything in that problem set that remotely resembles your solution. We can see that your solution is equivalent to $$kqr\left[\frac{1}{r^2-dr\cos\theta}-\frac{1}{r^2+dr\cos\theta}\right] = kq\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\left[\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+(z-d/2)^2+d^2/4}-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+(z+d/2)^2+d^2/4}\right]$$

Comment: I can't fix it now but the last terms in both denominators should be negative, not positive.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The solution is on the first page. The only difference is he used $d$ for the separation where Griffiths used $2d$. I changed it so the problems would be equivalent. Okay I see what you did but it doesn't seem like it could be made to equal the desired function. Do you not think they are equivalent?

Comment: How can they be equivalent? What happens when you plug in $(0,0,z)$ ? (is it the same as plugging in $(0,0,z)$ to Griffiths' ? ) Intuitively if your spherical coordinates looks like a subtraction of polynomial terms it's something to be suspicious of, as that's sparingly the form these things take.

Answer (score 2):

We know for sure that (ignoring the $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$)
\begin{align}
\Phi_{\text{cart}}(x,y,z) &=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +(z-d)^2}}  - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +(z+d)^2}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +z^2 -2zd + d^2}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +z^2 +2zd + d^2}}
\end{align}
is the right answer for this image charge problem. Now, if we convert this to spherical coordinates, we get the function
\begin{align}
\Phi_{\text{spherical}}(r,\theta,\phi) &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 -2rd\cos \theta + d^2}} -
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 +2rd\cos \theta + d^2}},
\end{align}
which is clearly very different from what you got. I'm not sure how you arrived at $r\mp d\cos \theta$ in your denominators, but you must have done something wrong in your geometry (draw a figure similar to Figure $3.13$ (but of course modified for this particular problem) and then apply the cosine law carefully again to obtain the distance).